# Prevent figure from being written to the temporary directory

Tags: plot, sas

When outputting figures to disk, I like to suppress all output in SAS to force the user (me) to look at the actual file which is created.  To do this I set the following options.

```
ods listing;
ods noresults;
goptions
  reset   = all
  rotate  = landscape
  xpixels = 1294
  ypixels = 800
  device  = png
  gsfname = outPlot
  gsfmode = replace
;
```

My plot call procedure may then look something like:

```
filename outPlot 'C:\Users\...\My Output Directory\Figure.png';

proc gplot data = plot_data;
    plot y_value * x_value = symbol / 
      haxis   = axis1 
      vaxis   = axis2 
      legend  = legend1
;
run;
quit;

filename outPlot clear;
```

As I understand it, this redirects the listing to my desired output directory.  However, in my log, I see something like this:

```
NOTE: 51820 bytes written to C:\Users\...\Temp\1\SAS Temporary Files\_TD6828_2UA3331QB3_\gplot6.png.
NOTE: 51832 bytes written to C:\Users\...\My Output Directory\Figure.png.
```

This indicates that the figure is first written to disk in the temporary folder and then written to the directory I want.

I'm looking to speed up the plot creation and suspect that this extra write to the temporary directory slows things down.

Is there a way to write only to my chosen directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have multiple ODS destinations open.  By default I think Enterprise Guide and the Base SAS Editor will both open the HTML destination.  If you are opening the listing destination in addition to that then that probably accounts for the second output.

To find out which ODS destinations are open, you can look in `dictionary.destinations` (or equivalently `sashelp.vdest`). See [support.sas.com/kb/33/590.html](http://support.sas.com/kb/33/590.html) .

You can also use:

```
proc sql noprint; 
  select destination into :openDestinations separated by ', ' 
  from dictionary.destinations ; 
quit;

%put &=openDestinations;
```

Another option is to just close all open destinations and then open just the one you want:

```
ods _all_ close;
ods listing;
```

Comment: Yes, it appears that I still had the HTML destination open.  Open destinations are stored in `dictionary.destinations` (or equivalently `sashelp.vdest`).  (http://support.sas.com/kb/33/590.html)  If you're like me and like things printed to the log rather than switching screens, the following could also be used: 
  `proc sql noprint;
    select destination
    into : openDestinations separated by ', '
    from dictionary.destinations
    ;
  quit;

  %put &=openDestinations;`

Comment: @LoremIpsum Nice find.  I'll update the answer, thanks.